# Visual basic SQLITE & Online Php My Admin

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, phpmyadmin

I would like to ask is there any way to capture the status of newly inserted and modified in each rows?

I heard my friends talking about it.

For an example:

I would like to know that which rows is just inserted and just modify previously.

Comment: Use a timestamp and a flag which rows you did not look at.

Comment: hmm which means i can retrieve the last inserted and update data?

Comment: That is your homework to manage this. I can give you a hint what I think the best thing to do... but remember, there is no timestamp-support in SQLite. You will have to code it your way.

Answer (score 0):

Once data has been inserted or modified, it is no longer distinguishable from other data. SQLite does not automatically create history information.

If you want to record history information, your application has to do this itself, or you could add [triggers that record this information](http://www.sqlite.org/undoredo.html).